# What is the best way to do a subscriber system?

Tags: php, mysql

I have doodled out many ideas but none of them are easy & efficiant. Does anyone have any ideas on how to make it so that on my website another user can subscribe to another. should i make a table and do it like this make a new entry for every time someone subscribes someone?

Comment: +1, but title is somewhat misleading.

Comment: What is the problem? How to store subscription relationships or how to actually deliver posts?

Comment: Regardless what you do with MySQL, it's common that at least you have one table ;). Really, what is your concrete question, why are you unsure?

Comment: How to store who is subscribed to who.

Comment: users can subscribe to other users?

Comment: Yeah, for example i have a a post system. and if a member wants another members posts to show in there feed they will subscribe to them.

Comment: I don't know where the +1 is in that.  -1.

Comment: I thought it was an interesting problem, that's where the +1 was

Comment: @syntheticsaint, sorry your question was closed.  If you edit it, and provide what you've tried, it could be reopened.  The structure of your current database would also be nice to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each user should have a unique ID.  Give the subscriber a list of subscribed IDs, and when you load their feed, check the IDs and load data from those too.

It's the simplest and most straight forward.  A comma separated list should suffice.

Comment: How do you manage it, if one user subscribes and another user unsubscribes *at the same time* with a comma separated list?

Comment: If you use a database as opposed to flat (text) files, you do not need to worry about exactly simultaneous (un)subscriptions.

Comment: The list is a saved for each user (in their entry of the table in the database).  I don't think one user performing two requests at the same exact time is all that likely, if possible.  If it's two separate users there will be no chance of collision since they are separate entries.

Comment: Lets say i had a table called 'subs' inside that are two fields userid and subs. How would i store the subscribed members? Would it be like this userid: 1 subs: 3,5,8,2? IF so how would i use that in PHP?

Comment: Yeah.  And then in PHP you could `explode` on commas, somehow turn that into an SQL query (I'll leave that up to you), get the data you want about users 3, 5, 8 and 2, and format that into HTML.  Most of it is highly dependent on your application.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON array to list user IDs to which each user is subscribed.